# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS but memory is not being deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting an occasional crash in a released app and from crash reports know the line its occurring at and type of crash - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS - but I don't know how the memory could becoming invalid because the lifetime of the object that is being referenced is the lifetime of the app and is not being deleted unless the app is terminated. So if the crash is not due to accessing deleted memory (because that memory is not being deleted) what other reasons could there be for the EXC_BAD_ACCESS in this particular situation?

Here's the code:

```
 @interface Model()
 @property (strong, nonatomic)   NSMutableDictionary*  cityAndStateDictionary;
 @end


- (NSString*) findAddress: (NSString*) key
{
    if (key == nil)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    NSString* cityAndState = (self.cityAndStateDictionary)[key]; // Crash here
}



@implementation Model
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        dispatch_async(modelQueue(), ^{
            [self readCityAndStateData];
        });
    }
}


- (void) readCityAndStateData
{
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[Model class]];
    NSString *filePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"CityState" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSError* __autoreleasing  nserror;
    NSDictionary* jsonParser = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data
                                                               options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                 error: &nserror];
    if (nserror == nil)
    {
        self.cityAndStateDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *item in jsonParser)
        {
            // create value object
            (self.cityAndStateDictionary)[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

`readCityAndStateData()` is being created and populated within a thread and if `findAddress()` is called before that has completed then cityAndStateDictionary would be nil and so the call to `(self.cityAndStateDictionary)[key]` in findAddress would just be nil.
The `cityAndStateDictionary` object is *not* being deleted anywhere therefore the crash should not be due to accessing deleted memory.

What reason could there be for the crash?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000010624ae60
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018356446c -[__NSDictionaryM objectForKey:] + 108 (NSDictionary.m:543)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183564450 -[__NSDictionaryM objectForKey:] + 80 (NSDictionary.m:538)
2   Name Of May App                 0x0000000100021f38 -[Model findAddress:] + 268 (Model.m:590)
3   Name Of May App                 0x00000001000beb78 _TTSf4g_n_n___TFC14Caller_Name_ID28BlockedNumbersViewController17formatBlockedCellfT6callerCS_6Caller3rowSi_CS_11BlockedCell + 1688 (BlockedNumbersViewController.swift:395)
4   Name Of May App                 0x00000001000bf1b0 _TTSf4g_g_n___TFC14Caller_Name_ID28BlockedNumbersViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView12cellForRowAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 528 (BlockedNumbersViewController.swift:0)
5   Name Of May App                 0x00000001000ba01c _TToFC14Caller_Name_ID28BlockedNumbersViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView12cellForRowAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 76 (BlockedNumbersViewController.swift:0)
6   UIKit                           0x0000000189af5aa8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 688 (UITableView.m:10803)
7   UIKit                           0x0000000189af5cc0 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80 (UITableView.m:10848)
8   UIKit                           0x0000000189ae33c4 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2152 (UITableView.m:2273)
9   UIKit                           0x0000000189afacb0 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 120 (UITableView.m:12556)
10  UIKit                           0x0000000189893774 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176 (UITableView.m:7390)
11  UIKit                           0x00000001897adf98 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1200 (UIView.m:14232)
12  QuartzCore                      0x000000018699e274 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148 (CALayer.mm:8937)
13  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186992de8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292 (CALayer.mm:8817)
14  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186992ca8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32 (CALayer.mm:2345)
15  QuartzCore                      0x000000018690e34c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252 (CAContextInternal.mm:1689)
16  QuartzCore                      0x00000001869353ac CA::Transaction::commit() + 504 (CATransactionInternal.mm:420)
17  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186935e78 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 120 (CATransactionInternal.mm:793)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018362c9a8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1802)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018362a630 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:1898)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018362aa7c __CFRunLoopRun + 956 (CFRunLoop.c:2849)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018355ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
22  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184fc5074 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
23  UIKit                           0x0000000189815f74 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:4089)
24  Name Of May App                 0x000000010003a8b4 main + 56 (Database.swift:17)
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018256959c start + 4
```

Comment: I'd go with an issue of concurrent calls... Doing a async call in the `-init`, I don't thinks that's recommended. I'd go with creating a block on `findAddress` instead, and do the same as we do for loading image in UITableView.

Comment: Kicking off an async process in an `init` isn't a problem;  it is oft done for expensive initialization processes.   However, you are correct that this is most likely a concurrency issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutable dictionaries are not thread safe.

You need to ensure that the dictionary is only every accessed from a single thread.

Note that `dispatch_async` from `init` is not a problem.  But it is unlikely to be necessary in this case.   Did you measure the execution time of your `readCityAndStates` method to determine if it is actually a performance issue?   As well, instead of storing that static resource as JSON, you should store it in a binary format.  That will parse much much faster and will, more importantly, cut the size of your app bundle.

Comment: It can take 2 or 3 seconds for the dictionary to be populated.  What's the best way of ensuring its only accessed from a single thread?

Comment: First, move to using a binary storage format.  NSArchiver should do the trick.  I bet that will be fast enough.   Next, that dictionary should only be populated once since, by definition, a resource from the app's main bundle cannot change.   If the binary format isn't fast enough then, and only then, should you consider how to make it thread safe.